# Is it possible to use a REST or web API in a Java Swing application

Tags: java, rest, swing, webapi

I have a Swing application that is done except for the web API part.
They have a REST API, but when I was looking at example of using a REST API in Java, they all use a Java web application, and I can't find any for a desktop swing application.
So is it still possible to do so?

Comment: Do you want to expose or to consume a web service?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

You can Consume (access and read) a REST web service in Swing desktop application.

You can achieve it using `HTTPClient`.

An example - http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-apache-httpclient/

Answer (score 7):

Use Spring RestTemplate an example [here](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/).

```
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate()
rest.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/WebApp/ServiceName", requestBean, Response.class);
```

This should return an object of type Response. For other HTTP operations supported by RestTemplate see the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can grep [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/72/websvc/jersey-rcp-client.html) example: Creating RESTful Service Clients in NetBeans Modules. The example shows how to create a twitter java-swing based desktop client with OAuth support (SWING).

Also you can grep [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayfv5m4vSMw) video tutorial for eclipse platform (SWT)

[Here is](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2014/10/22/getting-started-with-javafx-8-developing-a-rest-client-application-from-scratch/) a JavaFX example for RestFULL client

There is very good example of rest desktop client in [RESTful Java Web Services](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/restful-java-web-services) by Jose Sandoval. Try it on google/books